# Not able to run azure logic apps locally using VScode and Azurite

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps

I am using VSCode to create and test my logic apps locally. I have created a simple HTTP trigger and response for it. I have installed all the components and versions correctly. I am getting below error when I run my logic apps,

```
**Workflow Error: operationName='WorkflowDefinitionProvider.ProcessWorkflow', message='Workflow 'test-1' validate and create workflow failed, the error is 'One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'.) (Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'.)'', exception='System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'.) (Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'.)
[2022-05-03T02:52:23.134Z]  ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'.
[2022-05-03T02:52:23.136Z]  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**
```

It is also giving me below error in the logs,

```
**ErrorCode:
[2022-05-03T03:08:44.593Z] ', extensionVersion='1.0.0.0', siteName='UNDEFINED_SITE_NAME', slotName='', activityId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.
[2022-05-03T03:08:44.595Z] The listener for function 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' was unable to start.
[2022-05-03T03:08:44.595Z] The listener for function 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack: Unexpected HTTP status code 'NotFound'. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**
```

The process to test that I am following,

1. Start azurite in VSCode
2. and then Execute function - func host start

Anyone has any clue or faced similar problems? I am using logic apps first time.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to test HTTP triggers locally you need to

"*To locally run webhook-based triggers and actions, such as the built-in HTTP Webhook trigger, in Visual Studio Code, you need to set up forwarding for the callback URL.*"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code

Comment: My flow worked couple of times before even without adding ngrok or call back URL.. thats where I am getting confused.. what caused it to stop working.. I am following the same document except those last steps..Thank you for your inputs